# Не сохраняются данные в модель через modelForm

Tags: python, django

Не могу понять, что именно не так в Django проекте. Хочу реализовать следующее:

Создать на странице `forms.ModelForm` - `forms.ChoiceField`, для того чтобы из формы `Choice` выбрать оценку, ввести имя в поле, отправить и оценка с именем записались в БД.

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import RatingForm
from django.views.generic.base import View


class AddRating(View):
    def post(self, request):
        form = RatingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form = form.save(commit=False)
            form.rating = request.POST
            form.save()
        return render(request, 'firstapp/index.html', context={'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Rating


class RatingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        fields = '__all__'

    RATING_CHOICES = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
    )
    rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RATING_CHOICES)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models


class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Оценки')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Имя пользователя')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Оценка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Оценки'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AddRating.as_view(), name='add_rating'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body class="container">
<form action ="{% url 'add_rating' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (**«почему этот код не работает?»**) должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.